# Browser-based SSO ID token validity

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake supports [caching browser-based SSO authentication using an ID token](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#using-connection-caching-to-minimize-the-number-of-prompts-for-authentication-optional). Any idea how long this token is valid for? I can't see any mention in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

At least a cached MFA token is valid up to 4h.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-mfa.html#label-mfa-token-caching